# How do I remove the "Upload" and "Cancel" buttons from the PrimeNG p-fileupload component?

Tags: angular, file-upload, primeng, angular13

I'm using Angular 13 with PrimeNG 13.  I want to allow a file upload in my form so I have created

```
  <p-fileUpload [maxFileSize]="1000000" [customUpload]="true" [multiple]="false" formControlName="myFile"></p-fileUpload>
```

This creates a single file dialog with "Choose", "Upload" and "Cancel" buttons.  It seems that after choosing a file, I must then click "Upload" to get the file into my form.

Is there a way to create the component so that it only allows for upload of a single file and that initially choosing the file adds it into my form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [documentation](https://primefaces.org/primeng/fileupload) you should add below properties:

```
mode="basic" 
[auto]="true"
```